# Objective C: Drag and Drop Multiple Images

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to apply Drag and Drop function on different images that i have but my code isn't working, it has no effect on the images on my view.

Here's my code:

```
    if([touch view]==imageOne){
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        imageOne.center=location;
        return;
    }

    if([touch view]==imageTwo){
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        imageTwo.center=location;
        return;

    }
    if([touch view]==imageThree){
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        imeageThree.center=location;
        return;

    }
    if([touch view]==imageFour){
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        imageFour.center=location;
        return;

    }
    if([touch view]==imageFive){
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        imageFive.center=location;
        return;

    }
```

Comment: What is imageOne, imageTwo, etc.,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` property of UIImageView to `YES`. By default it will be `NO`. For more info, see [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889)